# When should one opt for a Isomorphic Javascript application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, isomorphic-javascript

There are a whole lot of new tutorials and examples popping up about this Isomorphic thing with react.js and how good it is.

For beginners like me, it is quite difficult to decide if this is needed or not.

Short example:
My application will be most of the time offline. The user will be able to create a questionnaire/survey and interview people who will answer this. After the questionnaire/survey is completed, he will need to call the node.js backend to download a Word document based on the answers.

So basically im asking if there is any reason creating an Isomorphic web application when it is a small simple and offline based?

Is there any simple node.js (express.js) + react.js + redux.js tutorial/exmplae out there which is not over complicated like the Isomorphic ones?

Answer (score 0):

My true story, the suggestion is, the choice always follows the need.

when to use isomorphic infrastructure :

1. heavily SEO requirement, especially when u have to render same value in front-end & back-end.
2. global state management and business logic, relatively maintainable.

However, if you have an existed API or backend server (no matter nodejs or not) , the isomorphic could not be a better solution. BTW, You can just emit the backend codes in these isomorphic boilerplate (what I exactly do).

I recommend [este](https://github.com/este/este)